# "EOF when reading a line" in chaquopy

Tags: python, android, flutter, chaquopy

I'm trying to build Python code editor in my android app using Flutter with [`chaquopy`](https://pub.dev/packages/chaquopy).

I already followed all the instruction in Flutter pub.dev to build it. The app can run successfully But when I want to do input() method, it shows EOF error. Is it possible to fix this problem? How to fix it?

[image: Error]